# How can I install xone XBox dongle drivers in Fedora Silverblue?

Tags: fedora

I would like to use my XBox One controller in Fedora Silverblue. However, the drivers from https://github.com/medusalix/xone rely on DKMS, which is not supported in Silverblue. Is there any way to get these drivers to work?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the drivers to work, although it requires a lot of manual steps:

1. Install cabextract: `rpm-ostree install cabextract`
2. Blacklist mt76x2u: `echo "blacklist mt76x2u" >> /etc/modprobe.d/local-dontload.conf`
3. Reboot
4. Clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/medusalix/xone.git`
5. Enter the directory: `cd xone`
6. Build the modules: `` make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD ``
7. Download, extract, and rename the dongle firmware:

```
driver_url='http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2017/07/1cd6a87c-623f-4407-a52d-c31be49e925c_e19f60808bdcbfbd3c3df6be3e71ffc52e43261e.cab'
firmware_hash='48084d9fa53b9bb04358f3bb127b7495dc8f7bb0b3ca1437bd24ef2b6eabdf66'

curl -L -o driver.cab "$driver_url"
cabextract -F FW_ACC_00U.bin driver.cab
mv FW_ACC_00U.bin xow_dongle.bin
```

8. Allow firmware to be loaded from the current dir: `echo -n "${PWD}" >/sys/module/firmware_class/parameters/path`
9. Load a module dependency: `modprobe ff-memless`
10. Load the modules: `for f in xone-gip.ko xone-wired.ko xone-dongle.ko xone-gip-gamepad.ko xone-gip-headset.ko xone-gip-chatpad.ko xone-gip-guitar.ko; do insmod $f; done`

Note that steps 8, 9, and 10 need to be done every time you boot. You may want to script them in `~/.bashrc` or something similar.